# What changes to Mockingjay Part 2 were made due to P. S. Hoffman's passing?

Tags: character, production, the-hunger-games, the-hunger-games-mockingjay-2

Actor Philip Seymour Hoffman, who portrayed a character in **The Hunger Games**, passed away during the middle of filming for the **Mockingjay** movies. His character, Plutarch Heavensbee, is a central figure in **Catching Fire** and **Mockingjay Part 1**. After seeing **Part 2**, I can say he had a notable lack of importance, though the plot itself may have lent to that analysis, as the movie focuses on the war action more than the political machinations of its prequel.

According to an interview by Director Francis Lawrence:

> "[Hoffman] had two substantial scenes left and the rest were appearances in other scenes. We had no intention of trying to fake a performance, so we rewrote those scenes to give to other actors… The rest, we just didn’t have him appear in those scenes. There’s no digital manipulation or CG fabrication of any kind."

<sub>(Bravo to the crew on this decision, post-mortem digitalization is beyond the pale...)</sub>

From my viewing, I believe one of those substantial scenes was **The outro following Coin's death, where Haymitch reads a letter from Plutarch to Katniss.**

Is this one of the significant scenes, and which are the other scenes that were changed?

Comment: "The rest, we just didn’t have him appear in those scenes. There’s no digital manipulation or CG fabrication of any kind." - Having scene *The Hunger Games: Mockingjay - Part 2* recently, I find this hard to believe. A CGI Phillip Seymour Hoffman really stood out to me at one point.

Comment: @DrRDizzle just <strike>got my mind blown to itty bitty bits</strike> saw it a few hours ago, and I notice no Redenbacher'ed Plutarch. Maybe I was distracted.

Comment: @DrRDizzle - I saw some CGI in at least one point. There was a view where Plutarch was standing in line with his head turned towards the left pointing at the camera. IIRC, it was during one of Coin's speeches. You could definitely tell Hoffman's image was imposed over someone else's. The lines were blurry around the face and it didn't quite fit correctly on the body. A very poor job, if you ask me.

Comment: @cde Why did you roll back my edits? Why shouldn't Hoffman's full name be used in the title? And "during the middle of filming for" is simply bad English, it's either "during filming" or "in the middle of filming", but not a combination of both.

Comment: @BCdotWEB I don't agree it was bad English. If anything the edit was grammatically wrong. It wouldn't be "during filming" it would be "while filming". Filming not being a noun, and his passing not being on stage/being filmed.

Comment: Congratulations, this question is the winner of the [corresponding topic challenge](http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/2015/49).

Comment: You seem to be quite defensive about this question, judging from your two rollbacks on it :-)

Comment: I did not change the meaning of the post, I corrected a few grammatical errors in a question, which otherwise,  I quite liked. However, "it's prequel" means "IT IS prequel", which does not make sense. I also corrected that error but you've changed it to its previous version. You want the possessive pronoun "its". The other errors which I edited, you have accepted, or changed into the  plural. E.g. * Which other scene was changed?* you changed into the plural which is fine, but your original post had: *which is the other scenes* I opted for the singular noun because you mentioned two scenes.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to Nina Jacobson, the producer, in [this answer on Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-did-the-tragic-death-of-Philip-Seymour-Hoffman-alter-the-Hunger-Games-franchise?no_redirect=1):

> Practically, Phil had shot about 80% of his scenes.  What we had to do with the remaining 20% was to give two key scenes to Liz Banks and Woody Harrelson.  In MJ1, Effie gives Katniss Cinna's design for the mockingjay uniform instead of Plutarch, as was originally scripted.  In MJ2, Haymitch reads a letter in a scene that, in the book and the original script, takes places between Katniss and Plutarch. Without a doubt, Phil would be a bigger presence in the movie if he had stayed with us.  I miss him at many levels.